# Erros ao Refatorar view html.erb

Tags: refatoração

Peguei template pronto(apenas pra prática mesmo) mas estou tento uma série de dificuldades para refatorá-lo:

1. CSS/JS não estão compilando (já tentei ir nos arquivos css e js e mudar para o path da pasta de imagens para assets/ não obtive exito)
2. imagens não rodas mesmo caso do css e js

os erros exibidos pelo terminal são:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pages/assets/photos/photo-25.jpg"):
de quase todas as imagens e dos css e js tbm. Já tinha refatorado alguns outros templates e não tive tanta dificuldade quanto estou tento com esse.
Se alguem puder me ajudar com algumas mudanças no então código, ficarei agradecido.

```
<!-- BEGIN head -->
<head>

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Botanica</title>

    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shortcodes.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="../../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.sexyslider-blog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#blog-slider").SexySlider({
                autopause  : true,
                auto       : true 
            });
        });
    </script>

<!-- END head -->
</head>

<!-- BEGIN body -->
<body class="top">


    <!-- BEGIN .main-body-wrapper -->
    <div class="main-body-wrapper">


        <!-- BEGIN .main-logo -->
        <div class="main-logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo-botanica-1.png" alt="" width="447" height="69" style="margin: 38px 0 0 0;" /></a>
            <!-- <div style="padding: 50px 0 0 0;">
                <a href="#" class="title">Rockstar</a>
            </div> -->
        <!-- END .main-logo -->
        </div>


        <!-- BEGIN .main-content-wrapper -->
        <div class="main-content-wrapper">

            <div class="deco-fruits-1"></div>

            <!-- BEGIN .main-content -->
            <div class="main-content">

                <!-- BEGIN .main-menu -->
                <div class="main-menu custom-font-1">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="homepage.html">Homepage</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="blog.html"><span>Blog</span></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="blog.html">Main blog list</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="post.html">Single post test entry</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="shortcodes.html">Shortcodes</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="photo-gallery.html"><span>Photos</span></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="photo-gallery.html">Photo gallery index</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="photo-gallery-list.html">Gallery image list</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="photo-gallery-single.html">Single image</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="contact-us.html"><span>Search</span></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <form action="#">
                                                    <input type="text" class="search" />
                                                    <input type="submit" class="submit" />
                                                </form>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <!-- END .main-menu -->
                </div>

                <!-- BEGIN .left-content-sidebar-wrapper -->
                <div class="left-content-sidebar-wrapper">

                    <!-- BEGIN .left-content -->
                    <div class="left-content">

                        <!-- BEGIN .blog-slider -->
                        <div class="blog-slider">
                            <div class="navigation" style="z-index:10;">
                                <div id="excerpt"></div>
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="control"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border" style="position: absolute!important; margin: 0 0 0 0px!important;"></div>
                            <div class="image-wrapper" id="blog-slider">
                                        <a href="#" class="border"></a>
                                            <img src="images/photos/photo-26.jpg" alt="&lt;a href=_.html#&quot;&gt;Aliquam lorem libero mollis malesuada consectetur&lt;/a&gt;" width="528" height="260" class="image" />
                                            <img src="http://botanica.orange-themes.com/wp-content/themes/botanica-theme/timthumb.php?src=http://botanica.orange-themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/13497754963.jpg&amp;w=528&amp;h=260&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="&lt;a href=_.html#&quot;&gt;Vivamus pharetra fringilla augue, a elementum ante ultrice.&lt;/a&gt;" width="528" height="260" class="image" />
                                            <img src="http://botanica.orange-themes.com/wp-content/themes/botanica-theme/timthumb.php?src=http://botanica.orange-themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/13497754451.jpg&amp;w=528&amp;h=260&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="&lt;a href=_.html#&quot;&gt;Aliquam lorem libero mollis malesuada consectetur&lt;/a&gt;" width="528" height="260" class="image" />
                            </div>
                        <!-- END .blog-slider -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- BEGIN .blog-list -->
                        <div class="blog-list">

                            <div class="item">
                                <h2 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Maecenas lacus nunc rutrum vitae phaaretra imperdiet</a></h2>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <a href="#" class="time">John Smith @ 09.07.2011</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="comment-nr">9 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-528x170.png" alt="" width="528" height="181" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-22.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                <p class="intro">Maecenas neque est, feugiat quis porta in, condimentum eget arcu. Maecenas fringilla aliquam ultricies. Pellentesque vel turpis nec leo tincidunt sollicitudin ac non risus. Ves tibu lum ultrices feugiat velit, quis tincid unt velit volutpat nec. Vivamus pharetra fringilla augue, a elementum ante ultrices tincidunt. Ut mi ligula, interdum ut pharetra.</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <h2 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Duis fringillectus vitae rutrum massa</a></h2>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <a href="#" class="time">John Smith @ 09.07.2011</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="comment-nr">9 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-528x170.png" alt="" width="528" height="181" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-23.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                <p class="intro">Ut nec magna libero, aliquet volutpat turpis. Sed vel neque at nulla condimentum pretium. Curabitur commodo magna eu arcu ultrices vel lobortis nunc faucibus. Nulla id lacus ut sem fringilla ullamcorper nec ut metus. In scelerisque elit vitae magna luctus gravida.</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <h2 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Maecenas lacus nunc rutrum vitae phaaretra imperdiet</a></h2>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <a href="#" class="time">John Smith @ 09.07.2011</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="comment-nr">9 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-528x170.png" alt="" width="528" height="181" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-24.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                <p class="intro">Maecenas neque est, feugiat quis porta in, condimentum eget arcu. Maecenas fringilla aliquam ultricies. Pellentesque vel turpis nec leo tincidunt sollicitudin ac non risus. Ves tibu lum ultrices feugiat velit, quis tincid unt velit volutpat nec. Vivamus pharetra fringilla augue, a elementum ante ultrices tincidunt. Ut mi ligula, interdum ut pharetra.</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <h2 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Duis fringillectus vitae rutrum massa</a></h2>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <a href="#" class="time">John Smith @ 09.07.2011</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="comment-nr">9 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-528x170.png" alt="" width="528" height="181" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-25.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                <p class="intro">Ut nec magna libero, aliquet volutpat turpis. Sed vel neque at nulla condimentum pretium. Curabitur commodo magna eu arcu ultrices vel lobortis nunc faucibus. Nulla id lacus ut sem fringilla ullamcorper nec ut metus. In scelerisque elit vitae magna luctus gravida.</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                            </div>

                        <!-- END .blog-list -->
                        </div>

                        <table class="pages-1 custom-font-1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="default"><span>1</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="active"><span>2</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="default"><span>3</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="default"><span>4</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="default"><span>5</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="default"><span>6</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    <!-- END .left-content -->
                    </div>


                    <!-- BEGIN .sidebar -->
                    <div class="sidebar">

                        <!-- BEGIN .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        <div class="sidebar-item">
                            <div class="latest-activity">
                                <div class="main-title-1 custom-font-1">
                                    <span>Latest activity</span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- BEGIN .tabs-1 -->
                                <div class="tabs-1 custom-font-1">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="#" class="tab-1 active"><span>Popular</span></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#" class="tab-1"><span>Recent</span></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#" class="tab-1"><span>Comments</span></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                <!-- END .tabs-1 -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- BEGIN .list -->
                                <div class="list">
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-70x70.png" alt="" width="70" height="78" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-13.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Proin luctus ullamcor ulputate nunc vitae</a></h5>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-70x70.png" alt="" width="70" height="78" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-14.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Aenean iaculis, risus eget sollicitudin pretiumligula</a></h5>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-70x70.png" alt="" width="70" height="78" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-15.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Pellentesque aliquet orcid ornare quamsit amet</a></h5>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                <!-- END .list -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- END .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- BEGIN .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        <div class="sidebar-item">
                            <div class="sidebar-photos">
                                <div class="main-title-1 custom-font-1">
                                    <span>Latest photos</span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- BEGIN .photos -->
                                <div class="photos">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-16.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-17.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-18.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-19.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-20.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-21.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-16.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-17.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-75x75.png" alt="" width="75" height="83" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-18.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END .photos -->
                            </div>
                        <!-- END .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- BEGIN .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        <div class="sidebar-item">
                            <div class="latest-news">
                                <div class="main-title-1 custom-font-1">
                                    <span>Latest news</span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- BEGIN .list -->
                                <div class="list">
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Proin luctus ullamcor vulputate nunc vitaetas</a></h5>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <a href="#" class="time">09.07.2011</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="comment-nr">9</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="intro">
                                            Cras vulputate dui at felis varius et consecte tur risus viverra. Vivamus commodo gravida malesuada.consequat dui.
                                        </p>
                                        <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Aenean sollicitudin varius nullaa ullamcorper turpis dictum ut</a></h5>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <a href="#" class="time">09.07.2011</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="comment-nr">12</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="intro">
                                            Praesent consequat velit id diam porta ut ultricies enim hendrerit. Morbi leo velit, consectetur at accumsan volutpat, bibendum
                                        </p>
                                        <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Phasellus ornare justo velnul</a></h5>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <a href="#" class="time">09.07.2011</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="section">Section</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="comment-nr">12</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="intro">
                                            Praesent consequat velit id diam porta ut ultricies enim hendrerit. Morbi leo velit, consectetur at accumsan volutpat, bibendum
                                        </p>
                                        <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END .list -->
                            </div>
                        <!-- END .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- BEGIN .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        <div class="sidebar-item">
                            <div class="latest-activity">
                                <div class="main-title-1 custom-font-1">
                                    <span>Latest news</span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- BEGIN .list -->
                                <div class="list">
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-70x70.png" alt="" width="70" height="78" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-13.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Proin luctus ullamcor ulputate nunc vitae</a></h5>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-70x70.png" alt="" width="70" height="78" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-14.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Aenean iaculis, risus eget sollicitudin pretiumligula</a></h5>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- BEGIN .item -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/image-overlay-70x70.png" alt="" width="70" height="78" style="background: url(images/photos/photo-15.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <h5 class="custom-font-1"><a href="#">Pellentesque aliquet orcid ornare quamsit amet</a></h5>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="more-link custom-font-1"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- END .item -->
                                    </div>
                                <!-- END .list -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- END .sidebar-item .latest-activity -->
                        </div>

                    <!-- END .sidebar -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>


                <!-- END .left-content-sidebar-wrapper -->
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="main-footer custom-font-1">
                    <p>Copyright &amp; design © 2012 ... •  <a href="#"></a></p>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/ico-youtube-1.png" alt="YouTube" width="23" height="21" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/ico-facebook-1.png" alt="Facebook" width="23" height="21" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/ico-twitter-2.png" alt="Facebook" width="23" height="21" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/ico-flickr-2.png" alt="Facebook" width="23" height="21" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/ico-rss-1.png" alt="Facebook" width="23" height="21" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- END .main-content -->
            </div>

        <!-- END .main-content-wrapper -->
        </div>


    <!-- END .main-body-wrapper -->
    </div>


<!-- END body -->
</body>
```

Segue o css principal

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font: 12px/19px Arial, serif; color: #483924; background: url(../assets/main-body-bg.png) 0 0 repeat fixed; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, span, p, form, input, ul, li, ol { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
h2 { font-size: 30px; line-height: 34px; }
h3 { font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; }
h4 { font-size: 20px; line-height: 26px; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; }
h6 { font-size: 13px; }

table, tr, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }

img { border: none; }

a { color: #f17400; text-decoration: none; border: none; }
a:hover { color: #f17400; text-decoration: none; }
a:focus { outline: 0; }

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=submit]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus { outline: 0 none; }

code { margin: 0 40px 25px 40px; padding: 20px 23px; color: #cfcfcf; border: 1px dashed #424242; background: #444444 url(../assets/code-bg.png) 0 0 repeat; text-shadow: #000 0 1px 0; line-height: 20px; display: block; }

.caps:first-letter { margin: 7px 6px 0 0; font-size: 40px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }

.clear { height: 0; line-height: 0; clear: both; }

.custom-font-1 { font-family: McLaren; }


/* #1 Layout structure */

.main-body-wrapper { background: url(../assets/main-body-wrapper-bg.jpg) top center repeat-x fixed; }

.main-content-wrapper { width: 962px; margin: 0 auto; background: url(../assets/main-menu-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; padding: 43px 0 0 0; }
 .main-content-wrapper .main-content { background: url(../assets/main-content-bg.png) 0 0 repeat; z-index: 20; position: relative; padding: 0 31px 30px 31px; }

.left-content-sidebar-wrapper { padding: 30px 0 0 0; margin: -35px 0 0 0; background: url(../assets/left-content-sidebar-wrapper-bg.png) top right repeat-y; z-index: 20; position: relative; }

.left-content { width: 528px; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 30px; }

.full-width-wrapper { padding: 0 31px 0 31px; z-index: 20; position: relative; }

.sidebar { width: 250px; float: right; margin: 0 30px 0 0; }
  .sidebar .main-title-1 span { background: url(../assets/sidebar-bg.png) 0 0 repeat; }

.more-link { width: 82px; height: 22px; padding: 1px 0 0 10px; font-size: 9px; line-height: 19px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; float: left; background: url(../assets/more-link-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; text-shadow: #000 0 1px 0; }
.more-link:hover { color: #ffba00; }

.main-title-1 { margin: 0 0 25px 0; background: url(../assets/border-2.png) center left repeat-x; overflow: hidden; color: #b3ab9f; text-align: center; }
 .main-title-1 span { font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 0; background: url(../assets/main-content-item-bg.png) 0 0 repeat; padding: 0 10px; }
```

Bom os problemas seriam esses, se algum puder ajudar fico grato.

Comment: Você está utilizando Ruby on Rails certo? Por que não está utilizando os helpers `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` para incluir seu **css** e **js**? E o `image_tag` para suas **imagens**?

Comment: Esta pergunta tem imenso código... dá para editar a pergunta retirando código em excesso (podes juntar um pastebin)?

Comment: Desculpa sergio irei fazer isso. De fato Daniel estão faltando os stylesheets, mas mesmo assim os css e o js não carregam. Quanto as imagens com a presença do image_tag algumas carregaram, Na minha pasta assets/images eu tenho outra pasta chamada photos é como se ele não encontrasse a referida pasta mas sei que estou apontando para a pasta, vou reduzir o código e ser mais direto.